# Nested ul css tags

Tags: html, css, nested

```
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>another</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I only want to style the nested ul tag... is this possible? I know I can just give the ul an id or class, but I was wondering if there was another way (I think:first-child, last-child, nth-child, may be at play here?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ul ul` that means any `ul` that's a child of another `ul`, no matter how many levels down it is.

If you want to target THAT level, specifically, you could go with `ul > li > ul` which would target `ul`s that are direct children of `li`s that are direct children of `ul`s.

Answer (score 0):

Tidy.exe do not recognise the format

```
UL
  LI
  /LI
  UL
  /UL
/UL
```